# Dynamic dependent dropdown laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, drop-down-menu

So, basically I want to create a dynamic dropdown on my form.

[image: sasaran's dropdown]

[image: indikator's dropdown]

1 sasaran has many indikators, so what i want is, when i clicked 1 of the sasaran, indikator's dropdown will show up the indikator that belongs to that sasaran.
here's my view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="sasaran_id">Sasaran</label>
                        <select id="sasaran_id"
                            class="selectpicker form-control @error ('sasaran_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="sasaran_id">
                            <option selected disabled>--silahkan pilih sasaran berikut--</option>
                            @foreach ($sasaran_id as $datasasaran)
                            <option value="{{ $datasasaran->id }}">{{$datasasaran->sasaran}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @error('sasaran_id')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div id="indikatorSection">
                        <div class="form-row align-items-end ml-2 indikator">

                            <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                                <label for="indikator_id">Indikator</label>
                                <select id="indikator_id"
                                    class="form-control @error ('indikator_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    name="indikator_id[]">
                                    <option selected disabled>--silahkan pilih indikator berikut--</option>
                                    @foreach ($indikator_id as $dataindikator)
                                    <option value="{{ $dataindikator->id }}">{{$dataindikator->indikator}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('indikator_id')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {{ $message }}
                                </div>

                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <label for="target_kinerja">Target</label>
                                <input type="number" name="target_kinerja[]"
                                    class="form-control @error('target_kinerja') is-invalid @enderror"
                                    id="target_kinerja" placeholder="" value="{{old('target_kinerja')}}">
                                @error('target_kinerja')
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                    {{ $message }}
                                </div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>


                            <div class="form-group col-md-1">
                                <button type="button" id="tambahIndikator" class="btn btn-primary"> Tambah </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**js**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name=sasaran_id]').change(function() {
            var url = '{{ url('sasaran') }}' + $(this).val() + '/indikator';
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                var select = $('form select[name=indikator_id[]]');
                select.empty();
                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.indikator + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**indikatorModel**

```
public function sasaran()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\ModelPerencanaan\SasaranModel');
    }
```

**sasaranModel**

```
public function indikator()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ModelPerencanaan\IndikatorModel','sasaran_id');
    }
```

**routes**

```
Route::get('sasaran/{sasaran_id}/indikator', 'UnitKerja\Perencanaan\RabController@cariIndikator');
```

**controller**

```
public function cariIndikator($sasaran_id)
    {
        $sasaran = SasaranModel::find($sasaran_id);
        return $sasaran->indikator()->select('id', 'indikator')->get();
    }
```

it works well when i tried the url on route.. but it seems my js didnt work :/ is there something i miss?

[image: the data]

Comment: start debugging the javascript

Comment: What's your JS doing exactly? Is there any ouput in your console or a weird behaviour?

Comment: @EnriqueBermúdezequest is okay.. but i got error, it seems that i cant select name with array.. how to fix this? https://prnt.sc/qg75q6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh i found the answer myself.. so basically after debugging the javascript i found that i cant select name with array so, what  i need to put is [name="indikator[]"]. then the code change as below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('select[name=sasaran_id]').change(function() {
            var url = '{{ url('sasaran') }}' + '/' + $(this).val() + '/indikator';
            console.log(url);
            $.get(url, function(data) {
                var select = $('form select[name="indikator_id[]"]');
                select.empty();
                $.each(data,function(key, value) {
                    select.append('<option value=' + value.id + '>' + value.indikator + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```